# Using Regex Plus Function in Python to Encode and Substitute

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to substitute something in a string in python and am having some trouble. Here's what I'd like to do.

For a given comment in my posting:

```
"here are some great sites that i will do cool things with! https://stackoverflow.com/it's a pig & http://google.com"
```

I'd like to use python to make the strings like this:

```
"here are some great sites that i will do cool things with! <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http%3A//stackoverflow.com</a> &amp; <a href="http://google.com">http%3A//google.com</a>
```

Here's what I have so far...

```
import re
import urllib

def getExpandedURL(url)
    encoded_url = urllib.quote(url)
    return "<a href=\"<a href="+url+"\">"+encoded_url+"</a>"

text = '<text from above>'
url_pattern = re.compile('(http.+?[^ ]+', re.I | re.S | re.M)
url_iterator = url_pattern.finditer(text)
for matched_url in url_iterator:
    getExpandedURL(matched_url.groups(1)[0])
```

But this is where i'm stuck. I've previously seen things on here like this: [Regular Expressions but for Writing in the Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140182/regular-expressions-but-for-writing-in-the-match#142188) but surely there's got to be a better way than iterating through each match and doing a position replace on them. The difficulty here is that it's not a straight replace, but I need to do something specific with each match before replacing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `url_pattern.sub(getExpandedURL, text)`.

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0)
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable; if a callable, it's passed the match object and must return a replacement string to be used.